# Not able to access a textview by findviewbyId method in my created kotlin file from a xml file (not Main_Activity.xml)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview, findviewbyid

I am new to Android Development. And I have written the code for the Recycler view for the first time.
I am building the Affirmations App with the help of the Android Developer [Training](https://developer.android.com/training/) Program. My Code is completely the same as the stated solution code of this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-recyclerview-scrollable-list?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-recyclerview-scrollable-list#4). But I am not able to access the layout file as well as the textview in it, in my ItemAdapter.kt file. Below is the code

```
    package com.example.affirmations.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.affirmations.model.Affirmation


/**
 * Adapter for the [RecyclerView] in [MainActivity]. Displays [Affirmation] data object.
 */
class ItemAdapter(

    private val context: Context,
    private val dataset: List<Affirmation>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder.
    // Each data item is just an Affirmation object.
    class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(com.example.affirmations.R.id.item_title)
    }

    /**
     * Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(com.example.affirmations.R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    /**
     * Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.textView.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringResourceId)
    }

    /**
     * Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

I am facing error at line no. 26 (R.id.item_title) and 36 (R.layout.list_item)

Code of list_item.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</resources>
```

On running the app it gives error like this

```
Can't determine type for tag '<TextView android:id="@+id/item_title" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>'
```

Thank you!! in advance

Comment: You'll have to post your `list_item.xml` layout file too, seems like that's where the problem is. FYI it's better if you post the actual stacktrace from your logs, it contains a lot of useful info that can tell you (or us!) exactly what's going wrong. But I'm guessing you haven't run it, and it's the IDE giving you warnings (maybe because the layout file doesn't exist?) - if you hover over the error it'll tell you what the problem is

Comment: edited the question please check it. And on hovering over the error it is giving me Unresolved reference: item_title and Unresolved reference: list_item

Answer (score 0):

change your ItemViewHolder class and onCreateViewHolder function to

```
class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
}
```

and

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }
```

You should be importing your list_item from resource(R) folder.
You are using: (com.example.affirmations.R.layout.list_item, parent, false) 
BUT
you should use (R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

Comment: Still Not solved

Comment: post the GitHub repo, You have  not attached some files

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is Solved. I just need to create the list_item.xml file in the layout directory. I created it just randomly in the resources folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).